# Code to create a CTE returns empty/null table

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbeaver

I'm trying to make a CTE for future reference in my SQL file. I'm working out of DBeaver using Postgres. This is the table that I'm trying to reference as the CTE:

```
SELECT userID, MIN(eDate) as levUpDate
FROM e_live
WHERE eName= 'missCom'
and puzzleNumber = '100'
GROUP BY userID
```

When I run this code by itself, it produces a normal table. However, when I try to create a CTE from it, as such, no table is created:

```
WITH tbl AS
(SELECT userID, MIN(eDate) as levUpDate
FROM e_live
WHERE eName= 'missCom'
and puzzleNumber = '100'
GROUP BY userID)
```

If I try to later reference tbl, I get the following error: "Error: Relation "tbl" does not exist." I'm not sure if this is an obvious syntactical error that I'm missing or a weird quirk related to the database I'm using? Thanks!

Comment: You cannot create a CTE for future reference. This `WITH ...` clause is always a part of `SELECT`, `UPDATE` or `INSERT` statement. Read more [in the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)

Comment: If you want the definition to persist, you probably actually want a `VIEW` instead. Try `CREATE VIEW tbl AS SELECT userID, ...`

Comment: @klin I'm not certain it is the answer - not enough information in the question to be sure. That's why I commented instead...

Comment: Sorry, should have included more info, this is what I meant by later reference:

`SELECT *
FROM tbl
JOIN user_metrics on tbl.userID = user_metrics.user_id`

This is the second part of my code.

Will try out this solution though — thank you!

Comment: Even when I run this code with CREATE VIEW instead of WITH, and then run the second part of the code, I get the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Can you edit with the full query that results in `Error: Relation "tbl" does not exist`?

Answer (score 0):

From the original posted question, your CTE is missing a clause at the end.  Basically, you define the CTE, but you don't select from it.  The CTE `tbl` doesn't get persisted, so you cannot `SELECT * FROM tbl` later:

```
edb=# create table e_live (userID int, eDate timestamp, eName text, puzzleNumber int);
CREATE TABLE

edb=# insert into e_live values (1,now(),'missCom',100);
INSERT 0 1


edb=# WITH tbl AS
(SELECT userID, MIN(eDate) as levUpDate
FROM e_live
WHERE eName= 'missCom'
and puzzleNumber = '100'
GROUP BY userID) select * from tbl;
 userid |         levupdate         
--------+---------------------------
      1 | 08-NOV-19 06:52:53.588546
(1 row)


edb=# select * from tbl;
ERROR:  relation "tbl" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from tbl;
                      ^
edb=#
```

If you wish for the results to be stored for later reference, you can create a view:

```
edb=# CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW tbl AS SELECT userID, MIN(eDate) as levUpDate
FROM e_live
WHERE eName= 'missCom'
and puzzleNumber = '100'
GROUP BY userID;
CREATE VIEW

edb=# select * from tbl;
 userid |         levupdate         
--------+---------------------------
      1 | 08-NOV-19 06:52:53.588546
(1 row)
```